# What are exactly the "criterios de corrección idiomática"?

Tags: gramática, rae, dialectos

I'm confused about the definition of the following criteria which is used in **"construcción textual"**.

- Ilación
- Brevedad
- Adecuación
- Coherencia
- Cohesión

**What exactly are they** and **how** do they apply on paragraphs or texts? Is *this related* to the dialects in Spanish language? I mean, dialecto estándar and superestándar?

Are these norms related to write a proper text? Can someone help me to address the mentioned questions? The issue which confuses me the most is **Adecuación**, which I couldn't find examples of: where is it applied and how are these five criteria defined by RAE? Overall what's exactly **"corrección idiomática"**? It would be very helpful to me if the answer would define the first and build up from there.

Comment: This is more about how to write a text (in general) than about Spanish. It's not about dialects. It has to do with how you should structure a text in order to make it "good" (by certain standards, mostly applicable to essays and opinion pieces). We covered some of these briefly in a translation course (in English). Where did you get these from?

Comment: @pablodf76 I got this from an old practice sheet where there was a text and to spot if any of these criteria were transged or whether it applied in such a case. Overall does it exist a proper definition of them?. The text belonged to communication. Perhaps can you offer some help?

Comment: Adecuación, coherencia y cohesión are commonly studied in high school, especially since they are part of the SAT syllabus (in Spain at least). That means you should be able to find lots of good resources just by googling them. Ilación is mostly a characteristic of cohesión, and brevedad is self-explanatory, but most students would consider it a sign of good adecuación.

Comment: @Yay I would not say anything about SAT''s here.